# Converting CSV file to JSON in android studio. The CSV file has saved on the server side

Tags: java, android, json, csv, pojo

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.a);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF- 
8")));
String line = "";
try{
reader.readLine();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
    WeatherSample sample = new WeatherSample();
    sample.setLeftHipAngle(Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]));
    sample.setLeftKneeAngle(Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]));
    sample.setRightHipAngle(Double.parseDouble(tokens[4]));
    sample.setRightKneeAngle(Double.parseDouble(tokens[6]));
    sample.setRealTime(Double.parseDouble(tokens[8]));
    weatherSamples.add(sample);    
}

} catch (IOException e) 
{
        Log.wtf("MyActivity", "Error reading data file on line" + line, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is my code. But in this case ,csv file has import to the resource folder. But I want to convert server side uploaded csv file into JSON format. Can you help me?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You have to download that file i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

```
api1 = ApiClient.getClient().create(Stock1.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> re = api1.getlist();
    re.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            Log.d("ttag", "chekc  "+response.body().byteStream());

            InputStream inputStream1 =response.body().byteStream();
            String line = "";

            try {

                reader.readLine();


                while ((line= reader.readLine())!=null) {

                    String[] token = line.split(",");

                    Log.d("TAG", this is 1st item of csv  "+token[0]);
                    Log.d("TGAG", "this is 2 item of csv  " + token[1]);

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```